# Firebase Cloud Messaging onMessageReceived not working with ShortcutBadger

Tags: android, android-service, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using Firebase Cloud Messaging to send notifications and ShortcutBadger to update the unread messages count on our app badge. I've extended the `FirebaseMessagingService` class and implemented the override method `onMessageReceived`, which seems to be working fine since I get notifications when my app is in the background or killed. However, when I add the `ShortcutBadger` call inside this method, I no longer receive notifications and the ShortcutBadger call does not work.

ShortcutBadger requires a `Context` and, since FirebaseMessagingService extends Service, it is a context, which is why I simply pass `this`. I also have ShortcutBadger working in other parts of my code, so I know it works.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
public class Notifications extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        ShortcutBadger.applyCount(getApplicationContext(), 1); // <-- now is working
    }

}
```

**EDIT: SERVER SIDE CODE**

Here's the server-side code that sends the Firebase message.

```
Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(null)
        .title(msg.getTitle())
        .badge(msg.getBadge())
        .body(msg.getMessage())
        .build();


Message message = new Message.Builder()
        .timeToLive(timeToLive)
        .delayWhileIdle(true)
        .notification(notification)
        .addData("text", msg.getMessage())
        .addData("title", msg.getTitle())
        .addData("line1", msg.getSubtitle())
        .addData("badge", String.valueOf(msg.getBadge()))
        .addData("qummute_notification", "true")
        .build();

Result result = send(message, deviceKey, retries);
```

It's been suggested that I send the message without the Notification payload.  Will try that and see what happens.

Comment: Did you try with application context?

Comment: Unfortunately I tried 'this' and 'this.getApplicationContext()' and neither worked.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: what type of Firebase message do you send from the server? This is very important

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you made sure that you are not calling `ShortcutBadger.removeCount(Context context)` while testing?
2. Try using `ShortcutBadger.applyCountOrThrow(Context context, int badgeCount)` to see if any exceptions are thrown.
3. The `onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)` is called on a background thread. Perhaps the phone/launcher you are testing on is using a badge that cannot be created and shown from a background thread.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle this situation from server side.Remove **Notification** from your JSON and Use **data**.
Remove Notification Hole object,
"notification": {
    "title": "My Title if any",
    "body": "location",
    "sound": "default"
  },

From where you are sending the notification you need to change that code,
For Server side code should be like below then your **onMessageReceived** method call even if app is in the background or killed.

```
{
  "registration_ids": [
    "cBbGxlj5JRI:APA91bFRLp3tDoBo_P5lGYGUZ4F6iJ55yBJq4GInL7RVV2asHR5PovqnMX-ekIdl_xOYyRyJmSe3SkxYMa3mzIvqml3MmLYZUh8JWygixIebhzhb_l4xv0Q-v3werKl_UO069G1uOyvq"
  ],
  "data": {
    "title": "alt_ctgry - Vehicle Number - extra detail(if any)",
    "body": "location"
  },
  "priority": "high"
}
```

if you want to create notification then write your own code for notification.
For Notification data access use below code,

```
@Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        Log.e("FCM", "Call onMessageReceived\n" + remoteMessage + "");

        String title = remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
        String body = remoteMessage.getData().get("body");

        createNotification(title, body);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> which seems to be working fine since I get notifications when my app is in the background or killed

No, `onMessageReceived` is called when your app in foreground but not background IF you have notification payload.

In your server side code you add notification payload, so previously your `onMessageReceived` also was not called when app in background but notification was shown by OS from your payload.

If you want to handle your push all the time you need to remove notification payload, but remember that it could break pushes on iOS if you have an iOS app.

Comment: Thanks.  We're going to remove the notification payload today and test see if that works.